# Blazorise DropDownItem ShowCheckbox not working

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, blazorise

I have just cut and pasted a Blazorise DropDown with checkboxes from the Blazorise docs into my code and it is displaying the menu without the checkboxes.

[image]

This is the code that I have used:

```
<Dropdown>
    <DropdownToggle Color="Color.Primary">
        Dropdown With Checkboxes
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
    <DropdownItem ShowCheckbox>Checkbox</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownDivider />
        <DropdownItem ShowCheckbox>Another Checkbox</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem ShowCheckbox Disabled>Checkbox Disabled</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Action</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

The same code on the Blazorise site daoes this:

[image]

All other Blazorise components work fine, just not this one. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I've just upraded to the lates version of Blazorise and the issue has resolved itself. Version 1.3.1 fixed it.